# How to forbid access to .htaccess File in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, .htaccess

If I call the .htaccess file in the browser e.g. https://www.mycompany.com/.htaccess, then it is getting downloaded. Is there a way to fix this?

I added this block to my .htaccess file, but it does not help:

```
<Files "\.htaccess">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

This is obviously a security hole.

Comment: Doesn't your htaccess file has 0644 permission ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat, it has -rw-r--r-- (644)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this Code spinnet

```
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Do not use `<Files "\.htaccess">`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
<Files .htaccess>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```